# Nesting flexbox inside flexbox overflow. How to fix this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

So I was trying to get a header and some content to fit into the screen by having a div `#main` with `height: 100%` as a flexbox, just like this:

```css
#main {
    height: 150px; /* Using a fixed height here, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work */
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #aa0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #00aa00;
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main" class="flexbox">
            <div class="header">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div class="content scrollable">
                CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So now if `#content` overflows the height of `#main`, `#content`'s scrollbar will take over, and the header stays visible. Works like a charm so far.

My problem is now that I need to nest another combination of header and screen fitting content into the outer content, which I tried to solve with another nested flexbox:

```css
#main {
    height: 150px; /* Using a fixed height here, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work */
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #aa0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #00aa00;
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main" class="flexbox">
            <div class="header">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div class="content flexbox">
                <div class="header">
                    HEADER
                </div>
                <div class="content scrollable">
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically I want both headers to stay up top now, and have only the inner content box scroll once it overflows. But when it does, the content stretches beyond (?!) `#main`'s height, triggering the browser pages's scrollbar instead of its own one. I suppose the problem may be caused by the outer content box, whose height is only defined by the outer flexbox.

I already had tried a solution where the headers would have absolute positions, but this doesn't quite work out for what I need it. Flexboxes would be just perfect if it wasn't for this problem.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Can you specify what is the desired behavior? You want the second header to scroll together with the content, under the first header?

Comment: Updated my question. I want both headers to stay up top, and have only the inner content box scroll once it overflows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask for is already happening in Chrome. Which makes me think you're developing with FF.

---

**As a side-note**, I believe that's a mistake, simply because you're developing for less than 15% of your target audience to only fix browser differences for another 65% of your audience. Luckily for you, they both keep tight to standards and differences are quite few these days.
Another reason why you might prefer Chrome over FF as a development tool is that FF has consistently been 6 months behind regarding dev tools for at least 4 years now. Don't get me wrong, I'm not a big Chrome fan and I fully welcome using FF as browsing device of choice. But, as a development tool, it's just not the best available. And they're both free.

---

Back to your question, adding `overflow-y:auto` to `.flexbox` seems to fix it in FF, too:

```css
#main {
    height: 150px; /* Using a fixed height here, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work */
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #aa0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #00aa00;
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main" class="flexbox">
            <div class="header">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div class="content flexbox">
                <div class="header">
                    HEADER
                </div>
                <div class="content scrollable">
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                    CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: of course, you'd need to run your code through a [prefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) for a wider browser coverage. Mind the "*filter*" box below it. Set to `> 0%` for maximum cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I didn't think this would actually do the trick. Thank you!
Regarding your side-note, thank you for this information, I actually do work on Firefox and I wasn't aware about the working differences this would have on Chrome. Since this is kind of a private project though I don't think that working with Chrome will be necessary. I'll keep your advice in mind anyway. :)

Comment: @StrikeAgainst, I'm a frontend developer by day and I love Linux, but based on the same principle above I try to develop/test as much as possible in Chrome, on Windows, so my code works for more people out of the box, before cross-OS/cross-browser/cross-device phase. I might not like it, but it's more efficient. Regarding your issue, because it didn't happen on Chrome, your question was really confusing for most people viewing it. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah that's a thing I never thought about before, I should keep that in mind for the future. Happy coding too you as well ;)

Comment: @StrikeAgainst As seen here, it is Chrome that doesn't behave (IMHO should also overflowed), so I recommend you stick to the browser you are used too and like the best (I do), and do thorough test on the rest. I also posted an answer, explaining where and why this issue occur, and IMHO, the best way is to know why things doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Since this fails in more than Firefox, I edited the tag list, and you might want to edit your answer.

Comment: I never claimed Chrome is correct, @LG. I just said using it for development is more efficient and better, overall. It's a sane decision to code for 65% and adjust for the rest than to code for 15% and adjust for the rest. Besides, it's known dev tools source makes it into FF 4 to 6 months later than in stable Chrome. About the answer, apart from not testing in IE, OP asked *"Can anyone help me fix this?"*. Which I did, without claiming I know flexbox technical details, which you master. If they asked for an explanation I wouldn't have bothered, I respect your monopoly on the tag. Chapeau!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks. And I never said you said _"Chrome is correct"_ :) ... simply shared my way of looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

This issue affects not only Firefox, also Edge and IE11 overflow the parent.

It's caused by the fact that flex item's `min-height`* defaults to `auto`, and as such can't be smaller than its content. (Chrome tries to fix this by itself, hence it works on it, though, IMHO, it shouldn't)

** Very well explained here: [The Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size/36247448#36247448)*

The affected element is the `<div class="content flexbox">`, which will overflow because if this.

The solution is to change its `min-height` to `0`, and with that will allow it to shrink past content.

*For IE11, see notes/sample below.*

Stack snippet

```css
#main {
    height: 150px; /* Using a fixed height here, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work */
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    /*flex: 0 1 auto;                       default, so not needed  */
    border: 2px solid #aa0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #00aa00;
    min-height: 0;                      /*  Firefox, Edge  */
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="flexbox">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content flexbox">
    <div class="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="content scrollable">
      CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As IE11 being a lot buggier, the above isn't enough, and there is 2 ways to fix it:

Using `flex: 1 1 0%`, which will make IE11 believe there is no content, hence will only grow as big as the available space in its parent.

```css
#main {
    height: 150px; /* Using a fixed height here, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work */
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    /*flex: 0 1 auto;                       default, so not needed  */
    border: 2px solid #aa0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 0%;                       /*  IE11, changed from "auto" to "0%" */
    border: 2px solid #00aa00;
    min-height: 0;                      /*  Firefox, Edge  */
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="flexbox">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content flexbox">
    <div class="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="content scrollable">
      CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `overflow: hidden` (see note at the end)

```css
#main {
    height: 150px; /* Using a fixed height here, otherwise the snippet wouldn't work */
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    /*flex: 0 1 auto;                       default, so not needed  */
    border: 2px solid #aa0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 2px solid #00aa00;
    /*min-height: 0;                        not needed, as overflow has same effect  */
    overflow: hidden;                   /*  Firefox, Edge, IE11  */
}
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="flexbox">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content flexbox">
    <div class="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div class="content scrollable">
      CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br> CONTENT
      <br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>CONTENT<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Note, using `overflow` with a value other than `visible` (its default), will have the same effect as `min-height`, where `hidden` is considered more safe than `auto`, avoiding future change in behavior to render a scrollbar.*

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using two `height: 0` on the main box and the content box.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.topheader {
  background: orange;
  width: 90%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}


.subcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 0;
  width: 90%;
  background: blue;
}

#container header {
  background-color: gray;
}

#container article {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;

}

#container footer {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <div class="topheader">
    Top Header
  </div>
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <header id="header">This is a header</header>
    <article id="content">
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.<br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines<br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines
      <br />
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
    </article>
    <footer id="footer">This is a footer</footer>
  </div>
</section>
```